Unable to make field private final
when try to hit REST API in swagger getting this below error,Would somebody help on this.
InInterceptor.java:215)\r\n\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:79)\r\n\t... 57 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to call setAccess() on Field 'name' (of class java.lang.NamedPackage) due to java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException, problem: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.lang.NamedPackage.name accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @446293d\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.checkAndFixAccess(ClassUtil.java:1008)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.fixAccess

Please provide a [MRE].

It looks like that code is trying to do something that modern versions of Java no longer allow. Show us what you exactly you are doing and tell us the versions of everything you are using.

Hello Thirukumaran , somewhere in your code, the setAccess() method tries (directly or indirectly) to access the name attribute without using the corresponding getter, locate it and change object.name to object.getName().

you should have  completed the [tour] :-/ It suggests searching before asking. Searching this site for [java] module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module shows results that can help/answer. (BTW the title missed the important part: "Unable to make field private final accessible", and is misleading)
